# I don't understand how this is working (MATCH_PARENT at View with layout_weight)

Tags: android, android-layout

When I set `MATCH_PARENT` for `View` + `layout_weight` the elements of the view behave strangely. Please can you explain why this is so. For example, here is the code on which to experiment. I can't understand the pattern. The less put the weight of the item, so it is more, however, it is unclear how many times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F0F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Testing for Yellow layout:** set `layout_weight= 0.5` > large?? how much bigger?  Did the elements shrink in size or were they thrown out of the parent?

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_weight="0.5"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#F00"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Update, PS:** I know how the layout will work with `WRAP_CONTENT` (or `0dp`). If you set `MATCH_PARENT` + `layout_weight`, then we have a fixed element size regardless of the content, when `WRAP_CONTENT` does not guarantee a fixed size from the content (and if the content size is increased, the element will be stretched). **I am only interested in the pattern MATCH_PARENT + layout_weight, because it guarantees the block size when the content size is exceeded.**

Answer (score 0):

> The less put the weight of the item, so it is more...

The reason is because you are assigning `android:layout_width` as `match_parent` to all LinearLayout. To get `android:layout_weight` worked, you **should** set `android:layout_width` as 0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give `android:weightSum`  to the parent of the layouts.

Secondly, if you have layouts placed horizontally next to each other then set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for each element.

Similarly, for vertically aligned elements, give `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

Comment: Hey, please try this solution. It will go with your updated ques too.